# MassAssignmentException in laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

i used laravel5...and want to store data in database and when press the submit than this error appeared

```
> MassAssignmentException in C:\xampp\htdocs\marriage\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php line 417: _token
```

my controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $custom =Request::all();
    Custom::create($custom);

    return redirect('custom');

}
```

model code

```
class custom_table extends Model
{
  protected $fillable=[
    'skin_color',
    'cast',
    'residence',
    'family_members',
    'hieght',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];
```

}

please help me how to resolve this error

Comment: Could you clarify your model structure a bit? You're calling Custom::create(), but pasted custom_table model.

Answer (score 2):

You are running into that error, because your Request is passing a "_token" attribute, and it is not Mass assignable.

You can exclude it using the except method, as such:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $custom = Request::except('_token'); // Exclude _token attribute
    Custom::create($custom);

    return redirect('custom');

}
```

Comment: I'd clarify that this is *probably* the cause. It's also possible that an additional form field not in the `$fillable` array is helping to cause it.

Comment: That could be the case, but his error message proves otherwise.

Comment: I think Laravel will fail on the first non-fillable field. I've learned to be explicit - had a guy fix the `_token` issue and get stumped when another field threw the same error and gave up until I made him read it again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell laravel what fields can be updated by the form, otherwise all the data in the form will be used to update the record even `_token` and `_method`

In your model:

```
class Cost extends Model
{
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = ['canbe', 'updated', 'byform];
}
```